# Apache Flink: Is there a way to transform queryable state before it is returned to the client?

Tags: apache-flink

Based on my reading of the docs, one must retrieve the entire state value associated with a key when using queryable state. I would like to be able to transform the value on the TaskManager before it is returned to the client, i.e. in the QueryableStateClientProxy or in the QueryableStateServer.

For example, in the case of MapState, it could be useful to be able to retrieve data for a particular key in the map and not have to return the entire MapState to the client (particularly if the MapState is large).

Am I right that there is no way to do this currently? And, if so, does anyone know if this might be on the roadmap somewhere? I see that the query state is marked as beta and may change in the future.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the current version (Flink 1.7.0), the fetched value cannot be modified before it is returned.
AFAIK, this feature is also not on the roadmap.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do you think there could be any interest in a PR for this functionality? And if I'm asking this question in the wrong place please let me know.

Comment: It might be useful. I'd reach out to the Flink dev mailing list or open a Jira issue to propose the feature. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for guidance -- I opened an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-11055) in Jira.

Comment: @GalenWarren AFAIK the answer indeed answers your question. Please mark it as done :-)